# How to declare a bean with its property value from user input in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a little application like a car game which I want to use Spring java config to manage the dependency of my beans.

There is a bean Car depends on bean Position which contains coordinate X and Y.
User should give the initial position of the car.

```
public class Car {

private Position p;
...
}

public class Position{
//value from user's input
private int x;
private int y;
}
```

So, How to declare the bean Position in Spring configuration class? How to pass the input value of X and Y to instantiate Position?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!!!

Comment: This sounds like it's probably not the best pattern. Please explain in more detail what the bean does and what the attribute means.

Comment: What kind of input? Keyboard input in the console? I don't think this is a good idea to do so. What about creating a property for the value of `x`, and injecting `Environment` to the constructor of `B` to get the value of that property and save it into `x` ?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. In fact, application is like a kind of car game. I define class 'Car' as class 'A' and a car should have its position (class 'Position' as class 'B') which contains the coordinate x and y. And the issue is user must give the initial position. Then user can give a suite of commands to make the car move to a new position.